# How to hide my A record? (like cloudflare)

Tags: dns, record, cloudflare

I'm interested in making my high protected server into a "like cloudflare" website.
I mean, what I want to do is to add DNS zones (domains) to my server, then point the A record to the real server and that way to protect them (when they resolve the domain, my server's IP should appear instead of the client's server).

I made these records:
DOMAIN.com A 1.1.1.1(ip)
WWW CNAME DOMAIN.com

The traffic does go through my server but when I resolve the domain I get the client's IP.
How can I hide this IP (like cloudflare does)?

Comment: You're probably seeing cached results

Comment: You should set the client server firewall to reject all connections not from your server.

Comment: When I use cmd to ping the domain, I get in result the client's IP. edit: I don't think so, since when I protect a site of mine on cloudflare, you can still access it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I work at CloudFlare.

Please do consider just opening a support ticket -- support.cloudflare.com -- and we'd be happy to discuss this with actual concrete examples so we'll be able to look at your specific situation.  Do note here though -- CloudFlare does not claim to hide your IP address. That isn't the service we claim to provide. We provide a performance and security service, any IP obfuscation is just a side effect.

Comment: I am not a customer of cloudflare, I doubt their support is going to help me doing that.

Comment: You could accomplish what you're trying to do with a load balancer it sounds like. Something like HAproxy, and then have the domains resolving to your client's back-end web servers transparently behind the HAproxy. There likely will be leakage in some ways, but it might at least make things a bit more difficult to find the back-end IPs.